# Sandbox account will not work on ecommerce site but a live account will

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, x-cart

I'm Using XCart 5.2.13 for a ecommerce site and when trying to make a test run with paypal express checkout I run into a error.  In test or production mode the sandbox account API credentials do not work.  I check twice to see if I made an copy paste error but I didn't.

Oddly enough when I put on the actual account and put on production the program works fine.

So I went digging into the server and found the log for the paypal checkout and found the parses are getting a error code of 10002 and telling me the security header is not valid.

I've been reading all I can on developer.paypal.com/ but haven't found a solution yet.

Any Ideas?

Update

I I've been trying different accounts to no avail and the last one I used gives me a failure to redirect message to paypal and the when I check the logs the response is NULL.

At least before It would of given me a code but now nothing.  I also contacted Xcart support as well

Answer (score 0):

10002 error indicates the sandbox account's API credential not correct. Please login https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run by your sandbox account to get the API credential, then copy and paste it again.

Comment: see I do that but I still get the same problem it fails to redirect to paypal checkout. I look at the logs and comes up the same error.  The only thing I can think of is a bug from xcart. It seems to not go to the test server.

Comment: On the Xcart Shopping cart page when I try to process to paypal express it says failure to redirect to paypal.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the security updates at Paypal.
You need to use TLS 1.2 for the sandbox.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US

**Please see the roadmap dates.**

Jan 14, 2016    After this date, Sandbox API endpoints only support new standard (HTTP/1.1, TLS 1.2 and SHA-256 certificates). 
This includes www.sandbox.paypal.com only accepting HTTPS for IPN Postbacks.

Jan 31, 2016    Production starts issuing API Credential Certificates with new standard (2048-bit, SHA-256).

Feb 29, 2016    Test Sandbox endpoints will be removed.

Mar 17, 2016    New SFTP IP addresses add to DNS for reports.paypal.com.

Apr 14, 2016    Old SFTP IP addresses removed from DNS for reports.paypal.com.

May 12, 2016    Old SFTP IP addresses stop working.

Jun 17, 2016    After this date, Production API endpoints will start moving to the new standard (HTTP/1.1, TLS 1.2 and SHA-256 certificates)

Sep 30, 2016    IPN postbacks to www.paypal.com only allow HTTPS

Jan 1, 2018 All Certificate API Credentials must have been upgraded to the new standard.